# Deconstruct a C# Tuple

Tags: c#, f#, tuples

Is it possible to deconstruct a tuple in C#, similar to F#? For example, in F#, I can do this:

```
// in F#
let tupleExample = (1234,"ASDF")
let (x,y) = tupleExample
// x has type int
// y has type string
```

Is it possible to do something similar in C#? e.g.

```
// in C#
var tupleExample = Tuple.Create(1234,"ASDF");
var (x,y) = tupleExample;
// Compile Error. Maybe I can do this if I use an external library, e.g. LINQ?
```

Or do I have to manually use Item1, Item2? e.g.

```
// in C#
var tupleExample = Tuple.Create(1234,"ASDF");
var x = tupleExample.Item1;
var y = tupleExample.Item2;
```

Comment: You're saying "compile error", please tell us which error, along with which Visual Studio version and/or C# compiler version you're using.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [Deconstruction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) but you should use C#7 for this purpose:

> Another way to consume tuples is to deconstruct them. A deconstructing
>   declaration is a syntax for splitting a tuple (or other value) into
>   its parts and assigning those parts individually to fresh variables

So the following is valid in C#7:

```
var tupleExample = Tuple.Create(1234, "ASDF");
//Or even simpler in C#7 
var tupleExample = (1234, "ASDF");//Represents a value tuple 
var (x, y) = tupleExample;
```

*The `Deconstruct` method can also be an extension method, which can be useful if you want to deconstruct a type that you don’t own. The old `System.Tuple` classes, for example, can be deconstructed using extension methods like this one:* ([Tuple deconstruction in C# 7](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2016/08/23/tuple-deconstruction-in-c-7/)):

```
public static void Deconstruct<T1, T2>(this Tuple<T1, T2> tuple, out T1 item1, out T2 item2)
{
    item1 = tuple.Item1;
    item2 = tuple.Item2;
}
```

Comment: C# 7 is not necessary, provided that you would install the following nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/.