# c# Inline tupel deconstruction into method args similar to JS's ... operator

Tags: c#, deconstructor

In my c# project a method returns a tuple. Is it possible to deconstruct the result of this method immediately inline and use it as arguments for another method call? I imagine something similar to the `...` operator in JavaScript.

```cs
public (string a, string b) GetTupelResult() {
    return ("result a", "result b");
}

public void MethodWithTwoStringParameters(string a, string b) {
    Debug.WriteLine(a);
    Debug.WriteLine(b);
}

public void Main() {
    // Deconstruct first, call later ==> WORKS
    (string a, string b) = GetTupelResult();
    MethodWithTwoStringParameters(a, b);

    // Inline solution ==> IS SUCH A THING POSSIBLE?
    MethodWithTwoStringParameters(...GetTupelResult());
}
```

Is there a way to achieve a single-line solution in c# *without modifying `GetTupelResult` and `MethodWithTwoStringParameters`?*

I know, that I could modify `MethodWithTwoStringParameters` to accept a tupel as parameter, or build a wrapper method/overload. But that is not the point I am trying to make.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deconstruct a C# Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217213/deconstruct-a-c-sharp-tuple)

Comment: @Ishmaeel No. Regular deconstruction, as described in that other question, works well in my code. I wonder, if there is a tupel-to-args converter/operator.

Comment: @MathewHD Sure, but this would call the method twice. I just posted a minimal example. In reality, the GetTupelResult gathers multiple data from a database and returns a complex result with different object types instead of string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass ValueTuple instead of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55588765/pass-valuetuple-instead-of-arguments) ... still - no

Comment: @Selvin Partially... It would require to modify the `MethodWithTwoStringParameters` method's parameters, or to build a wrapper for that.

Comment: you had asked about *a single-line solution* so .. no

Comment: @Selvin I've edited the question. Hopefully, it's more clear now.

Comment: `GetTupelResult().With(MethodWithTwoStringParameters)` ... `public static class Ext1
    {
        public static void With<P1, P2>(this ValueTuple<P1, P2> tuple, Action<P1, P2> action)
        {
            var (a, b) = tuple;
            action(a, b);
        }
    }` [...click...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xm4hov) ... but seriously what for ...

Comment: @Selvin Thank you. Nice to konw, that there is *some* way to do it. However, my intention of this question was, if there is a 1:1 equivalent of JS's `...` operator in c#, to simplify my existing code. As there doesn't seem to be one yet, I think that for readability purposes, I'd rather stick with the existing two-line solution I posted above. Thank you very much anyways! :)